# Strange Case Of MySql Server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

There is an interesting case that I would like to solve, I've used exception notification via email and got the following mail that says:

> MySql has gone away for query 'INSERT INTO sl_usermeta ( USER_ID, CREATED,DESIGNATION ) VALUES ( 7695, '2014-06-02 16:20:48', 'Manager')'.

This query executes in millisecond when I run this through MySQL. However the interesting fact to be noticed is there is a entry in database with the following values

> UserID----CREATED------DESIGNATION
>
> 7695------2014-06-02-----16:21:16

I've checked the logs and found the user did not send the same request again. I want to ask if MySQL retries the same query once it comes back after going away?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL itself cannot have done, since you weren't able to contact the server and it is therefore entirely unaware of your `INSERT` statement in the first instance.

However, whatever client you're using may well be retrying. Since you didn't tell us what that is, it's impossible to say.

Comment: No, Wordpress is not a MySQL client. It uses one, and will likely set some configuration on it. It's up to you to investigate those details.